# Get token for discovery service- ERCD-NOCONFIG error

Tags: discovery

I am getting the below error response while trying to get the token for Discovery service.

Request URL is

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https:/gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1
```

Response is

```
{  
   "code":403,
   "error":"Forbidden",
   "description":"2017-04-26T07:55:39-04:00, Error ERCD-NOCONFIG occurred when accessing https://127.0.0.1:443///watson-auth-token?Client-IP=203.99.198.95;Client-CN=;, Tran-Id: gateway-dp02-581750654 - "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't a technical one and I'm not sure if this will work for you but:

I have had the same issue with the Conversation Service just recently. That Gateway Error Code "ERCD-NOCONFIG" is pointing to the username and password credentials you are supplying to the Watson Service. When you create a service in bluemix, you either generate credentials manually or bind the service to an app (and a different set of credentials will be generated for you). You need to supply the **latter**'s credentials.

Here are some use cases:

1. You generated credentials manually, and you also binded the service to an app. Thus, you have two credentials. The manually generated credentials won't work on your binded app.
2. The Library reference stated that it "automatically reads the credentials from the VCAP_SERVICES" and because of that, you didn't delete your test credentials.